# How do I wrap text in ionic 7 labels or inputs as pervious answers no longer work

Tags: ionic7

In previous versions of ionic you could use <ion-label class="ion-text-wrap"

or

```
.item.sc-ion-label-md-h, .item .sc-ion-label-md-h{
  white-space: normal !important;
 }

 .item.sc-ion-label-ios-h, .item .sc-ion-label-ios-h{
   white-space: normal !important;
 }
```

Here are some examples of what the ionic docs say

html

```
<ion-input class="custom" label="Long Long Long Text Here"></ion-input>
```

scss

```
ion-input.custom {
   --background: #373737;
   --color: #fff;
   --padding-end: 10px;
   --padding-start: 10px;
   --placeholder-color: #ddd;
   --placeholder-opacity: 0.8;
  }
```

I tried adding

```
--white-space: normal !important;
```

ionic seems to be moving away from

```
<ion-label>Label Here</ion-label>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced the same issue, and here is what I came up with:

1. For consistency, I added the built-in `ion-text-wrap` class to the elements whose label I want to be wrapped, e.g., `ion-input` or `ion-textarea`.
2. And I added the following rule to `global.scss`:

```
[label].ion-text-wrap .label-text-wrapper > .label-text {
    white-space: normal;
}
```

It helped me, and I hope it will help you too.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in ionic 7 any where  has been replaced labelPlacement="".  you no longer have the ability to wrap text.  I will convert my project back to ionic 6